# Problem debugging sudo shell script executed from cron

Tags: shell, cron, sudo

I have a shell script which renews a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate. If I run it from a bash prompt it works fine. If I execute from the crontab it gets triggered but none of the commands seem to be executed.

The script is:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo docker stop home-assistant
sudo certbot renew
sudo docker start home-assistant
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

If I examine the letsencrypt log afterwards (/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log) there is no trace of the "certbot renew" command having been executed if it's run from cron. If I run it manually I see entries in this log.

syslog has this for the time the cron job is executed:

```
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER cron[106193]: (myuser) RELOAD (crontabs/myuser)
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER CRON[107237]: (myuser) CMD (bash -l /usr/bin/sudo /home/myuser/renew_ssl.sh)
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/pickup[106963]: 6E68F132832: uid=1000 from=<myuser>
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/cleanup[107242]: 6E68F132832: message-id=<20220901182701.6E68F132832@HP-MICROSERVER.localdomain>
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/qmgr[102195]: 6E68F132832: from=<myuser@HP-MICROSERVER.localdomain>, size=717, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/local[107244]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/local[107244]: 6E68F132832: to=<myuser@HP-MICROSERVER.localdomain>, orig_to=<myuser>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep  1 19:27:01 HP-MICROSERVER postfix/qmgr[102195]: 6E68F132832: removed
```

I've added this to /etc/sudoers to enable the script to run as sudo from the cron:

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/myuser/renew_ssl.sh
```

Any idea what I need to do to get this to execute properly from the crontab?

Comment: Your cron job is not running in root already? Mine doesn't need sudo if running from cron. So I would need sudo if running from the user prompt but not cron.

Comment: I added it to crontab using "crontab -e"

Comment: What is your cron record? Why do you run script with `sudo`, you use `sudo` already in the script commands

Comment: I've tried both of these variants, but neither works: "10 19 1 * * bash -l /home/myuser/renew_ssl.sh" and "27 19 1 * * bash -l /usr/bin/sudo /home/myuser/renew_ssl.sh"

Comment: To debug cron, add a log to your can calls.  `* * * * * SOME COMMAND >/tmp/cron.out 2>/tmp/cron.err`.  You might see something there.  Your question mentions certbot is not executed, is it set in the PATH for cron?  Call it with full path to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips. I managed to get output from the job, which pointed to permissions errors. So I used "sudo crontab -e" (which I wasn't previously aware of) to schedule the job to run as root, and now it runs fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by using `sudo crontab -e` to run the script as root (it was a permissions issue)